# How to make value auto update when input numbers are changed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, input, addeventlistener, onchange

Here is a [link to the tip calculator](https://wonderful-meninsky-e0b1c7.netlify.app/) - it's hosted on netlify.

I created a tip calculator using html, scss, javascript. no tutorials used, so I'm pretty proud. It took me waaayyyyy longer than I had planned on, but it's done. needless to say, I am a complete beginner.

In any event, I need some help.

I need to know how to make the numbers auto-update if I input a new dollar amount into the billing input.

For instance, if the bill is $50, and the tip percent is 50% that's a $25 tip Amount. for a total bill of $75 dollars.

But let's say I mistyped the bill, so I go back to put in $60, 50% of $60 is $30. so the total bill amount should auto-update to $90. But I can't figure out how to get all of that to happen instantaneously when I change the dollar amount in the billing input.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with using a "change" event listener. but I don't understand how to best implement it, or if that's even the answer here.

```
// Upper Box Selections

const tipPercent = document.querySelector(".tip-percent");
const tipSlider = document.querySelector("#tip-slider");

tipSlider.oninput = function () {
    billInput = Number(document.querySelector("#bill-amt").value);
    tipPercent.innerHTML = this.value + "%";

    //Discovered that number input type still returns a string
    //You can wrap multiple variables in parenthesis in order to append methods
    let tipAmount = document.querySelector(".tip-amount");
    // if a variable is referenced but not defined, it will be added to the window element - can now use in second function
    tipTotal = Number((billInput * Number(this.value / 100)).toFixed(2));

    tipAmount.innerHTML = "$" + tipTotal.toFixed(2);

    const billTotal = document.querySelector(".bill-total");

    billForSplit = Number(billInput + tipTotal).toFixed(2);

    billTotal.innerHTML =
        "<strong>$</strong>" + "<strong>" + billForSplit + "</strong>";
};

// Bottom Box Selections

// -Grab slider value
const splitSlider = document.querySelector("#split-slider");

splitSlider.oninput = function () {
    // -Grab split person value-split PERSON for 1, people for more than 1
    const splitPeople = document.querySelector(".split-people");
    if (splitSlider.value <= 1) {
        splitPeople.innerHTML = splitSlider.value + " person";
    } else {
        splitPeople.innerHTML = splitSlider.value + " people";
    }
    // -grab tip per person value
    const splitTip = document.querySelector(".split-tip");
    // -grab total bill per person value
    const splitTotal = document.querySelector(".split-total");
    // - tip per person equals tipTotal / split slider value
    splitTip.innerHTML = "$" + (tipTotal / splitSlider.value).toFixed(2);
    // -total bill/person = billTotal / splitSlider.value
    splitTotal.innerHTML =
        "<strong>$</strong>" +
        "<strong>" +
        (billForSplit / splitSlider.value).toFixed(2) +
        "</strong>";
};
```

https://wonderful-meninsky-e0b1c7.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function with a name like `calcTotal()` which will be run every time there is an input for the bill and tip:

```
const tipPercent = document.querySelector(".tip-percent");
const tipSlider = document.querySelector("#tip-slider");

function calcTotal() {
    billInput = Number(document.querySelector("#bill-amt").value);
    tipPercent.innerHTML = this.value + "%";

    //Discovered that number input type still returns a string
    //You can wrap multiple variables in parenthesis in order to append methods
    let tipAmount = document.querySelector(".tip-amount");
    // if a variable is referenced but not defined, it will be added to the window element - can now use in second function
    tipTotal = Number((billInput * Number(this.value / 100)).toFixed(2));

    tipAmount.innerHTML = "$" + tipTotal.toFixed(2);

    const billTotal = document.querySelector(".bill-total");

    billForSplit = Number(billInput + tipTotal).toFixed(2);

    billTotal.innerHTML =
        "<strong>$</strong>" + "<strong>" + billForSplit + "</strong>";
};
tipSlider.oninput = calcTotal;
document.querySelector("#bill-amt").oninput = calcTotal;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, I wish I had enough rep to upvote. Question, can you explain why the two last calcTotal calls did not need to be invoked with ()??

Comment: @richj_codes if you added the parentheses, it would run the function. Whatever is returned (if anything) will be what the onclick would be set to.